# PostgreSQL : How to design db schema for time series with lots of insert and deletes

Tags: postgresql, rdbms

I need to have data be INSERTED based on Date and Time (Minute granularity is enough)
But I will also DELETE all the rows as they are being processed

So you guessed it, something the be executed but not right now, so deferred actions I suppose you could say.

```
expiry | action
2020-01-30T10:45 | Action1
2020-01-30T10:45 | Action2
2020-02-05T00:00 | Action3
2020-02-05T00:00 | Action4
```

I will have millions of rows on certain days and hours of the day, and none on others.
I would do something like

```
SELECT expiry,action FROM <table> WHERE expiry > '2020-01-30T00:00' AND expiry < '2020-01-30T23:59'
```

and then eventually I would do something like

```
DELETE FROM <table> WHERE expiry > '2020-01-30T00:00' AND expiry < '2020-01-30T23:59'
```

or even

```
DELETE FROM <table> WHERE expiry < '2020-01-30T23:59'
```

What would the best way to model this in Postgres ? 
And what do I need to watch out for ?

Answer (score 0):

See if you can make use of Timescaledb, some benchmarks and info here:

[Link](https://blog.timescale.com/blog/timescaledb-vs-6a696248104e/)

There are several other option with which this can be done in PG as well, but just in case if PG is not the only thing you are looking at.

EDIT

---

**Create a function to create the partitions and indexes**

drop function test_partition_creation();

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_partition_creation( DATE, DATE )
returns void AS $$
DECLARE
    create_query text;
    index_query text;
BEGIN
    FOR create_query, index_query IN SELECT
            'create table test_'
            || TO_CHAR( d, 'YYYY_MM' )
            || ' ( check( time >= date '''
            || TO_CHAR( d, 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
            || ''' and time < date '''
            || TO_CHAR( d + INTERVAL '1 month', 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
            || ''' ) ) inherits ( test );',
            'create index test_'
            || TO_CHAR( d, 'YYYY_MM' )
            || '_time on test_' 
            || TO_CHAR( d, 'YYYY_MM' )
            || ' ( time );'
        FROM generate_series( $1, $2, '1 month' ) AS d
    LOOP
        EXECUTE create_query;
        EXECUTE index_query;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

**Partition creation for a given time period**

```
SELECT test_partition_creation( '2010-01-01', '2012-01-01' ) ;
```

**Trigger function creation**

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_partition_function()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE 'insert into test_'
            || to_char( NEW.TIME, 'YYYY_MM' )
            || ' values ( $1, $2 )' USING NEW.id, NEW.TIME ;
        RETURN NULL;
    END;

$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**Trigger activation**

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_partition_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON test
    FOR each ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_partition_function() ;
```

Ref to this [Link](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Month_based_partitioning#Create_a_function_to_create_the_partitions_and_indexes) for more details.

Comment: Thanx, good link, unfortunately I am not allowed to choose another database...

Comment: In this case your best bet can be partitioning the tables with a 24hr range on expiry column. Would that work for you ?

Comment: yes that would work, what would be the preferred amount of data to start using partitioning ? I googled and found when you reach 2 Gig you should consider using partitioning, would that be a good threshold ?
What would the performance impact be when deleting partition(s) ? with regards to e.g. indexing

Comment: when and once you want to delete the data you can just get rid of the partition to make sure there is no perf impact after the purge operations go ahead and run: "vacuum analyze" on the table.

Comment: but comparing to NOT using partitions, would the "normal"  DELETE row have significant impact on performance, since I expect the index to be rebuilt.

Comment: comparing using partitions and not using partitions, would the "normal"  DELETE row be heavy (performance wise) or "not so bad", since I expect the index has to be rebuilt. I mean is it really worth to use partitions, or is it even a must.  The fact that we drop partitions easily seems efficient, but if normal delete is not that big of a deal, then I do not want to over engineer the solution.

Comment: Any data you modify is versioned in postgres, not just delete but when you perform these operations with bigger volumes and depending upon your vacuum and analyze setting it needs to be vacuum’d and analyzed or it can have performance hit by using older plans with older stats. To answer if its a must or no it all depends upon your used case.